# Try to solve a dynamic SOQL query

Tags: dynamic-soql

```
String lvQueryUp = 'SELECT Id, StartDate__c, Name FROM CustomObject__c WHERE';

for(String lvindex : myIndexListName) {
    lvQueryUp += ' ( Name = ';
    lvQueryUp += '\'' + lvIndex + '\'';
    lvQueryUp += ' OR ';
    
}
lvQueryUp += ' ORDER BY StrartDate__c ASC';
List<CustomObject__c> lstIndexesUp = Database.query(lvQueryUp);
```

What I need to optimize this request????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be a dynamic query, as there are no dynamic elements. Consider a query bound to the parameter directly:

```
CustomObject__c[] lstIndexesUp = [
  SELECT StartDate__c, Name 
  FROM CustomObject__c 
  WHERE Name = :myIndexListName 
  ORDER BY StartDate__c ASC];
```

If you did need a dynamic query here, you could still use a binding variable:

```
String lvQueryUp = 'SELECT Id, StartDate__c, Name FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Name = :myIndexListName ORDER BY StartDate__c ASC';
List<CustomObject__c> lstIndexesUp = Database.query(lvQueryUp);
```

As a last resort, your code could be optimized to:

```
String lvQueryUp = 'SELECT Id, StartDate__c, Name FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Name IN '+
    '(\''+String.join(myIndexListName,'\',\'') +'\') ORDER BY StartDate__c ASC';
List<CustomObject__c> lstIndexesUp = Database.query(lvQueryUp);
```

I don't recommend this in most cases, as it can exceed the SOQL string length limit, and it also provides a way for [SOQL Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm), so this code (nor your own) should be used with input provided from a user.

In all cases, we're using the SOQL `IN` operator (binding to a list implicitly converts `=` to `IN` at runtime). This is the same as saying "Field = value1 OR Field = value2 OR ...".

If `myIndexListName` is actually a Set, you need to convert it to a List first for the last example:

```
String lvQueryUp = 'SELECT Id, StartDate__c, Name FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Name IN '+
    '(\''+String.join(new List<String>(myIndexListName),'\',\'') +'\') ORDER BY StartDate__c ASC';
List<CustomObject__c> lstIndexesUp = Database.query(lvQueryUp);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Do you think I need to use ' escapeSingleQuotes method' to avoid SOQL Injection??

Comment: @WildMan If you use the first two options in my answer, no. Escaping is automatically handled for you. If you use String.join, you must take care to do this yourself. Another reason to not try and build your own queries.

Comment: One more thing ! Why we don't need the "lvIndex String" ?

Comment: @WildMan You don't need `lvIndex` because there's no loop left to go through. As far as the other question, if you just need up to the top 2,000 records (or less), a simple query will suffice.

Comment: @WildMan Please open a new post if you have a separate question - comment threads should only be used to clarify this answer rather than to open a new topic.

Comment: Sorry sfdcfox, your last answer was deleted ! I post a new question: SOQL query to assess accounts based on opp...